# Simple progress bar in C# MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using LabVIEW in my company and would like to change to C# MVVM. On my autodidactic journey I feel like a total idiot, when stumbling over some things that are fairly easy to be done in LabVIEW but I simply cannot get done in C#.

After understanding the MVVM basics I am now trying to get a simple progress bar showing updates in a 1000 ms interval until full. But when executing the following code, the window shows up with an empty progress bar and after 4 seconds jumps to the final value of 100.

I think I am getting some absolute basic programming principle wrong, so I would be very grateful if you could help me with that. Thanks in advance!!

Here are the codes:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MicrosoftMVVMToolkit_Sandbox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MicrosoftMVVMToolkit_Sandbox"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar Width="500" Height="10" Value="{Binding Progress}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"></ProgressBar>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm;

namespace MicrosoftMVVMToolkit_Sandbox
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = vm;
        this.Show();
        vm.Work();
    }
}
}
```

ViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace MicrosoftMVVMToolkit_Sandbox
{
class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private int progress;

    public int Progress
    {
        get => progress;
        set => SetProperty(ref progress, value);
    }

    public void Work()
    {
        Progress = 0;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); 
        Progress = 25;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Progress = 50;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); 
        Progress = 75;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Progress = 100;
    }
}
}
```

============================

Solution 1 - await Task.Delay option:

Here is the exemplary code for the await Task.Delay option, in case that anyone else has the same problem:

```
    public async void Work()
    {          
        Progress = 0;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Progress = 25;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Progress = 50;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Progress = 75;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Progress = 100;
    }
```

Comment: Make `Work()` asynchronious to prevent UI block/freeze of `Thread.Sleep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is that the progress-bar can only be updated when the UI thread is not blocked. I.e. it is processing windows messages. `Thread.Sleep` will however block the UI thread, preventing it from doing any other work, including drawing your progress bar.

There are a few possible solutions

- Use an async method and use `await Task.Delay(1000)` instead of `Thread.Sleep`. This will allow the UI thread to do other work while waiting. But it will not work if you need to do anything processing-intensive.
- Run your work on a background thread, for example with `Task.Run`. But this leads to the next problem: you are not allowed to update any UI control from a background thread. For this there are two solutions:

  - Use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to update the Progress-property from the UI thread. (or any equivalent ways to run code on the UI thread)
  - Update the progress-field from the background thread, but use a separate timer to raise the `OnPropertyChanged` event for the Progress-property. The timer should be one that runs on the UI thread, like `DispatchTimer`. This has an advantage of allowing frequent progress updates without spamming the UI thread with messages.

Comment: Ok, I understand! I have already tried the await Task.Delay version and it worked. In case that somebody else has the same problem, I have added the implementation above.

Answer (score 0):

In constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = vm;
    this.Show();
    vm.Work();
}
```

`vm.Work()` blocks your code execution for 4 seconds (each call to `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)`)
It makes UI not responsible for that time.

You need to change progress bar `Progress` using some non blocking tool, like `DispatcherTimer`.

Example:

```
// remove vm.Work() from constructor

// add private field in MainWindow
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

// add in constructor
dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
dispatcherTimer.Start();

// add private method in MainWindow
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    vm.Progress += 1;
}
```

I didn't test this code.